# WPF Dictionary using DataTemplates on a DataTemplateSelector always having a null value for the key

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I have a dictionary on my DataTemplateSelector that holds a list of datatemplates. The constructor creates the dictionary holding DataTemplate properties as the value but the dictionary is always reflecting null values, meanwhile I can look at the **property** when the SelectTemplate is called and the property has the correct DataTemplate in it. What is going on  that the dictionary (which I thought was reference type) always show the initial 'null' value when the dictionary was created and not the object?

Is there anyway I can get this to work without scrapping the dictionary and using a switch? I was using it to avoid a giant switch statement, but I'm not sure why this isn't working.

View:

```
  <selector:NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector x:Key="sel">
     <selector:NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector.PageLoadedDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   ...
                </DataTemplate>
            </selector:NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector.PageLoadedDataTemplate>
    </selector:NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector>
```

DataTemplateSelector:

```
 public class NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    private Dictionary<string, DataTemplate> _dictionary;

    public NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector()
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, DataTemplate>();
        _dictionary.Add("PageLoaded", PageLoadedDataTemplate);
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)_dictionary["PageLoaded"];

            //return PageLoadedDataTemplate;  this works fine. The above dictionary is null for the value at this key.
        }
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }

    public DataTemplate PageLoadedDataTemplate { get; set; }
```

Comment: When the constructor of *NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector* executes, the *PageLoadedDataTemplate* still has the default **null** value - which is then being added to the dictionary in the constructor. The property is only being assigned *after* the constructor has finished (aka, the *NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector* instance has been fully created)

Comment: Yes, it's null in the constructor, but gets set when the view loads up & later the SelectTemplate is called. Is the dictionary not using a reference to the PageLoadedDataTemplate?

Comment: No, you put the *content* of the property into the dictionary - which is *null* (note, you do not put a reference to the property in the dictionary). Later on, the property will be assigned an object reference. Then, the *content* of the property is that reference, but this does not change the information/content stored in the dictionary (which remains *null*).

Comment: Oh I see, so would a better route be to update the dictionary when the property gets set then? Or how would you go about this scenario?

Comment: Exactly, you would update the dictionary in the setter of the property. (You would also need to implement the getter then, which would fetch and return the template from the dictionary.)

Comment: Could you post as answer so i can accept your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the constructor of *NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector* executes, the content of the property *PageLoadedDataTemplate* is still **null**, and this **null** value is being added to the dictionary.

Later - after the constructor returned and the *NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector* instance has been created - another value (a reference to a *DataTemplate* object) is being assigned to *PageLoadedDataTemplate*. However, while the content of the *PageLoadedDataTemplate* property is now different, the content stored in the dictionary still remains *null*.

To have the dictionary always reflect the current content of the *PageLoadedDataTemplate* property, update the dictionary in the property setter. By doing so, the getter must also be implemented - which should simply fetch and return the respective value stored in the dictionary.

```
public class NodePropertyGridTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, DataTemplate> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, DataTemplate>();

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            DataTemplate dt;
            if (_dictionary.TryGetValue("PageLoaded", out dt))
                return dt;
        }
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }

    public DataTemplate PageLoadedDataTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            DataTemplate dt;
            return _dictionary.TryGetValue("PageLoaded", out dt) ? dt : null;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == null) _dictionary.Remove("PageLoaded");
            else _dictionary["PageLoaded"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The example code given here avoids *null* values being stored in the dictionary. If it  the dictionary (or the property) should/can be accessed from different threads in a concurrent manner, it might be safer to use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).